# Sonarqube 7.9 fresh installation, unable to login

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube7

I've installed on Centos7: sonarqube 7.9 , postgresql 9.6.14, java 11.0.4.
Updated sonar.properties, indicated:
- sonar.jdbc.username
- sonar.jdbc.password
- sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
Configured Systemd service and adjusted firewall rules.

As result sonar service stars without any issues and sonarqube web page available by Centos7 VM ip address.
But when trying to login with admin\admin username and password , getting an error: Authentication failed.

Tried to reset admin password using following query, but still not able to login:

```
update users 
set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt= '6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' 
where login = 'admin'
```

Moreover tried to execute following query, which according to official docs applicable for SonarQube 7.9:

```
update users set crypted_password = '$2a$12$uCkkXmhW5ThVK8mpBvnXOOJRLd64LJeHTeCkSuB3lfaR2N0AYBaSi', salt=null, 
hash_method='BCRYPT' where login = 'admin'
```

But in users table column hash_method does not exist and got an error: value too long for type character varying(40).

Could you please advise how to reset default admin password and login?

Comment: Did you start with a new database or have you migrated an older database? If this is the case: did you migrate the database without any errors?

Comment: I've started with completly fresh installation of sonar and postrgesql database as well on completly new VM.

Comment: In that case the login should be the default one (admin/admin). To check your installation comment out everything in your SonarQube configuration file. Then it will use the default internal (test) database.